# How to append multiple image into a ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, opencv

I want to ask how to append multiple image into a ndarray

my image's shape is (300,300,3) and I use opencv read into a ndarray

which shape if (300,300,3)
but when I append another img2 to my first img.

it's shape return (5400,),it is lool like be flatten but I just append.

it want to use like :

```
                      img[0] #is my first image
                      img[1] #is my second image
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do this like how you would in regular python just convert it at the end

```
data = []
files = glob.glob ("*.jpg")
for myFile in files:
    image = cv2.imread (myFile)
    data.append (image)

print('data shape:', np.array(data).shape)
```